# Solr returns results with special char escapes

Tags: javascript, json, solr

I have Solr 4.6 implementation where data is imported and indexed from MySQL using DataImportHandler. All works great except when querying documents, Solr escapes special chars from the result, as an example a Json result looks like this:

```
"{\"responseHeader\":{\"status\":0,\"QTime\":1,\"params\":{\"indent\":\"off\",\"q\":\"group_search:germany\",\"wt\":\"json\"}},\"response\":{\"numFound\":284,\"start\":0,\"docs\":[{\"expiration_date\":0,\"
```

This is problematic when parsing the results with Javascript. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not Solr escaping the results... it's probably something else (like whatever you are using to query solr).
Try directly querying solr from the browser:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/query?q=group_search:germany
```

Or from the command line:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/query?q=group_search:germany"
```

Comment: You are right, the problem was in PHP json_decode, but thanks.